# Facebook Instant "PLAY" button not present

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-instant-games

My Facebook Instant app does not have a play button, so it's not possible to launch the app via sharing.

Could someone outline what I need to do to get this button to appear please?

I've set up everything (including an app page) in the dashboard. I'm assuming it has something to do with the "fbapp-config.json" file, but sample app doesn't seem to have the most common use case.

I assume don't need a self-hosted bot just to launch my app?

Comment: What have you tried? Could you please paste your relevant code parts?

Comment: Hi Nick, that's the problem. I don't have any code to paste because I don't know how this fits into the Instants system. Is it part of the fbapp-config.json file? Is it part of the bot system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed elsewhere (as I am unable to comment on Stack Overflow) I clarified that this is the Messenger share from the app details page. This looks like a bug on the Facebook side, as this reproduces for me.

For context, I am an engineer working on the Facebook Instant Games team. We will look into fixing this and update here when it is fixed.

[image]